# Parse json dynamically with Data.Aeson

Tags: json, haskell

I follow docs and try:

```
let st = do result <- decode "{\"name\":\"Dave\",\"age\":2}" --bss
            flip parseMaybe result $ \obj -> do
                     name <- obj .: "name"
                     return name
```

I get:

> No instance for (FromJSON b0) arising from a use of `.:' In a stmt of
>   a 'do' block: name <- obj .: "name" In the expression:   do { name <-
>   obj .: "name";
>          return name } In the second argument of`($)', namely   `\ obj
>        -> do { name <- obj .: "name";
>                return name }'

How to do it properly? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FromJSON b0` indicates that the type isn't fixed at this point. If you, however, fix the type, for example to `String`, it will work:

```
let st = do result <- decode "{\"name\":\"Dave\",\"age\":2}"
            flip parseMaybe result $ \obj -> do
                     name <- obj .: "name"
                     return (name :: String)
```